# Combinatorics of sets

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Let us take an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ . Consider $S=${${\text{1,2,3,}\cdots \text{n}}$} .

Call a **subset of $S$** to be ***X-sum-friendly*** if the sum of the elements of this subset is $X$ where $X \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X$ is  a divisor of $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Prove that $S$ can be partitioned into disjoint  ***X-sum-friendly*** **subsets** if $X \geq n$

Comment: please help me out :)

Comment: It's a very interesting question, but not so simple to answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately (it would have been much interesting otherwise) it is not always so. E.g.
$n=6$, $X=7$ you have $\left\{ {1,6} \right\},\left\{ {2,5} \right\},\left\{ {3,4} \right\},\left\{ {1,2,4} \right\}$
and for $n=7$ , $X=14$
$\left\{{1, 6, 7}\right\}, \left\{{2, 5, 7}\right\}, \left\{{3, 4, 7}\right\}, \left\{{3, 5, 6}\right\},\left\{{1, 2, 4, 7}\right\},\left\{{1, 2, 5, 6}\right\},\left\{{1, 3, 4, 6}\right\},\left\{{2, 3, 4, 5}\right\}$.  
Is yours a hypothesis, exercise ? what is the context where you found it? etc.

Comment: How to prove that the above result  mentioned by the OP fails for n=6,X=7