# Property on the divisor of $n(n+1)/2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $n\geq 0$ and $k\geq n+1$ be a divisor of $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$.

Is it true that there exists $k'\geq n$ such that $$0\leq k-k'\leq n+1$$ and $k'$ is a divisor of $\frac{(n+1)n}2$?

I came up with this problem while trying to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955349/combinatorics-of-sets). I may be close to a solution but I need the above property to be true, but I failed to prove or disprove it.

Thank you

Comment: As the question stands now, you can take $k'=k$...

Comment: @5xum thanks for the edit and for pointing out the typo. $k$ is a divisor of $(n+1)n/2$ not $(n+1)(n+2)/2$ ....

Comment: The way the question stands now, the answer is no, since $k$ can equal $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$, and since $k'$ is a divisor of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, you can see that $k'<k$, so $0\leq k'-k$ is not possible.

Comment: @5xum of course I wanted $k'\leq k$... Sorry to waste your time with typos like that ...

Comment: @wece: then double proofread what you write, $k'=k$ should be excluded.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't want to exclude $k'=k$. the case where $k=k'=n+1$ for example is still ok for me. But sadly their is a negative answer from 5xum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the statement is false for $n=10$ if $k=33$:

- $k$ is a divisor of $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}=66$ ✔
- $k\geq n+1$ since $33\geq 11$ ✔

So, what are the possible candidates for $k'$? Well, $k'$ must divide $\frac{n(n+1)}2=55$, so $k$ must be one of $\{1,5,11,55\}$

However, we want $k'<k$, so $55$ is out. But if $k'=11$, then $k-k'=22>11=n+1$, and the same is true for $k'=5$ and $k'=1$.